# Issues in PayPal live transaction via PayPal iOS SDK

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am developing an iOS application for iPad, version 7.x. We Need to perform PayPal transaction via the application. We included PayPal iOS SDK and referring their sample code to perform the transaction.

The sample code is placed [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/tree/master/SampleApp)

1. There are enough funds in the customer account
2. Also, we have proper Client ID and secret key where funds needs to be transferred.
3. Both payee and payer have live accounts.
4. Transaction via their Sandbox account was sucess

Upon debugging the code, we found that we are able to create the payment. However, we get error while the payment is about to be approved.

Here are the error details

```
PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: UNKNOWN_ERROR - System error (UNKNOWN_ERROR). Please try again later. (400) | PayPal Debug-ID: 3e8087cbf6bd1 [live, PayPal iOS SDK 2.1.2]
```

**Is there any specific configuration which we need to include in our code for making live transaction?
Or is there specific configuration that needs to be done, in one of the accounts?
Or is there something missing the sample code provided by PayPal iOS SDK? Please advice.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discussed this issue with PayPal Technical Support team, and here was the FIX:

```
We’ve found the issue is actually not with buyer account, some flag was not updated for merchant account "XXX@YYY.com” due to a bug which had in our system at the time it was created.

The fastest workaround to resolve this would be if you could please add another email to same account "XXX@YYY.com”. 

Steps to add another email address to  "XXX@YYY.com” :
Please login to the PayPal account.
Click on Profile—> Email address. Add another email address.
```

This solved our issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not using the correct ClientID. The client ID you are using is not associated with an active App from yoiur developer portal. To correct this, please go into the [developer portal](https://developer.paypal.com) and either use a different client ID from a different 'active' app or create a new app.